# Squish multiple rows in multiple columns into one row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to squish multiple rows into one row across multiple columns in pandas.

For example,

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,1,1,2,3], 'B':['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6'], 'C':['c','c','c','c','c','c'], 'D':['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6']})

print(df)
   A   B  C   D
0  1  b1  c  d1
1  2  b2  c  d2
2  1  b3  c  d3
3  1  b4  c  d4
4  2  b5  c  d5
5  3  b6  c  d6
```

here 'A' is the identifier to be used as reference for grouping rest of the rows across the columns and I'd like to convert the dataframe into the following format,

```py
print(df)
   A   B        C   D
0  1  b1,b3,b4  c  d1,d3,d4
1  2  b2,b5     c  d2,d5
2  3  b6        c  d3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['A', 'C'], as_index=False).agg(','.join)
```

[image]

Comment: Why is this returning an Empty Dataframe?